# command to update to the latest Firefox

Tags: package-management, software-updates

How can I update my firefox to the latest version on Ubuntu?

I tried `sudo apt-get update Firefox`, but it returns an error:

```
the update command takes no arguments.
```

Comment: Have you checked the man page?

Comment: why does this have three close votes for "unclear what you're asking"? it's crystal clear to me what OP is asking. they also clearly don't know how `apt-get update` works, but I honestly cannot fathom how anyone would think the question here to be not well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

The command you're looking for is

```
apt-get install firefox
```

This command installs Firefox or, if it's already installed, updates it to the latest available version in the repo.

Instead, the command `apt-get update` resyncs the package index files from the sources. It is usually done before a `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` (which update all packages in the system).